# Laptop transformer/AC adapter noisy ONLY when computer is working hard

Tags: laptop, power-supply

So, I've seen the questions asking the generic "Why is my transformer making noise?", but my situation seems to be different. It's intermittent. It's not a hum, but a sort of crackly sound that only seems to happen when I'm doing certain things under a heavy processor load. For example, clicking and dragging can cause this during the event, but it goes away when I release.

I know that clicking and dragging a mouse isn't hard, but I have 12 tabs open in Chrome and two instances of Adobe CC applications and this is a system with 3GB of RAM and an older duo-core processor.

Anyway - is this more common than I think? Is this a sign that the adapter needs to be replaced? Why would that even happen, theoretically? Does the system draw more power from the adapter as it's asked to do more and more?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is electrical interference rather then related to how hard the computer is working.  Does the problem occur when the computer is working hard but you are not doing IO ?   Does it happen when the battery is charged, or only when its discharged ?  (I have a laptop with a cheapo power supply which is quiet when the battery is charged, but makes a noise when the battery needs to be charged up - presumably its not coping with the additional load)

Comment: I've noticed it a couple of times when something was animating on screen. The battery is charged though I leave it plugged in.